# React and Firebase database - how to make multiple simultaneously update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update Firebase database with multiple simultaneously update. But I am getting an `Firebase.update failed: First argument contains a path that is ancestor of another path`.

My code to update the database looks like this:

```
onGoalAdd = (name, description, startDate, finishDate, remark, main) => {

    var newGoalData = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      startDate: startDate,
      finishDate: finishDate,
      remark: remark,
      main: main,
    };

    var mainGoalData = {
      main: ""
    }

    let myRefKey = dbRef.child('/goals/'+this.state.uid).push().key;

    var updates = {};
    updates['/goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+myRefKey] = newGoalData;
    updates['/goals/'+this.state.uid] = mainGoalData;

    dbRef.update(updates);

    this.setState({
      goalKey: myRefKey,
    });
  }
```

The desired result is to update database with all `newGoalData` under the `uid/myRefKey` and simultaneously add empty main property just under the `uid`.

What is the right approach, please?

Answer (score 0):

So this resolved my situation:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid);
    const mainGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid);
  }

  onGoalAdd = (name, description, startDate, finishDate, remark, main) => {
    let myRefKey = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid).push().key;
    this.dataGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid+'/'+myRefKey);
    this.mainGoalRef = dbRef.child('goals/'+this.state.uid);

    this.dataGoalRef.update({
      name: name,
      description: description,
      startDate: startDate,
      finishDate: finishDate,
      remark: remark,
    });

    this.mainGoalRef.update({
      mainGoal: ""
    });
    this.setState({
      goalKey: myRefKey,
    });
  }
```

Is there any better solution, please?

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar error.
The workaround was to append appropriate object key at the end of path in updates object and build updates objects key by key.

So in presented case something like this should work:

```
...
const updates = {};

for (const key in newGoalData) {
  updates[`/goals/${this.state.uid}/${myRefKey}/${key}`] = newGoalData[key];
}

for (const key in mainGoalData) {    // assuming that mainGoalData has multiple keys
  updates[`/goals/${this.state.uid}/${key}`] = mainGoalData[key];
}

dbRef.update(updates, error => {...some optional code...});

...
```